# Changing the url which the logo links to

Tags: navigation

I'm using Zen Theme 5.x and want that the site logo links non to the front page but another page in my base url, like to a contact page. It seems that I can achieve this modifying the page template file but I don't know how to do it. Could anybody help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do it.

Linking the logo to the front page has become a de facto standard. Linking it to the contact page would only confuse users who expect to go to the front page, while users who *want* to go to the contact page would probably not click the logo.

*Update in response to the comment below:*

In my opinion, a language selection front page is a bad idea. Remember that people come to your site in order to accomplish a task. That task is never to choose a language. Also, consider how you want Google to see your front page.

A better alternative is to serve the front page in a language determined y the [Drupal Language Negotiation API](http://drupal.org/node/1497272) and make it really easy for users to switch languages if they want to. Read more about multilingual front pages at [HowTo: Different home page (default front page) for each language](http://drupal.org/node/1216132) and [Drupal 7: Cracking the multilingual front page nut](http://bengoodyear.com/blog/drupal-7-cracking-the-multilingual-front-page-nut/).

Now, if you still want to change the url the logo and site name link to, enable the `THEMENAME_preprocess_page` function in your Zen sub theme (you did create a sub theme, right?) and alter value of `$variables['front_page']`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply marcvangend but maybe you considered my contact link example as the final result I want to achieve. In fact the reason I want to modify the link destination is that I have a multilingual site for which I made a frontpage where you can select your language before you go into the site, that is the home link in the language you select. Therefore I need to link the logo to this bilingual homepage link for not to confuse users.

Comment: Yes, I interpreted your example as your question. After all, it was the only information I had. If it was not the question you meant to ask, consider asking the true question next time. I will update my answer in reaction to the new information.

Comment: I think I didn't asked the wrong question but maybe didn't give the right example. I agree with you on the frontpage approach but I just wanted to know how to do the linking. Thank you for the links and the information you shared on how to modify the file.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with your site.